# how to get antd select value react js

Tags: reactjs, antd

I am using `antd` so I have a lot of fields some are inputs, selects, file uploads, and so on, in `antd` input component has a name attribute but I cannot see the name in `antd` select component when I select one of the options am getting 'cannot destructure currentTarget of undefined'

**Here is my onChangeHandler**

```
 handleChange = ({ currentTarget: input }) => {
    const errors = { ...this.state.errors }
    const errorMessage = this.validateProperty(input)
    if (errorMessage) errors[input.name] = errorMessage
    else delete errors[input.name]

    const data = { ...this.state.data }
    data[input.name] = input.type === 'file' ? input.files[0] : input.value
    this.setState({ data, errors })
  }
```

**how am using the select component in a reusable form**

```
renderSelect = (name, label, options) => {
    const { data, errors } = this.state

    return (
      <Select
        name={name}
        label={label}
        options={options}
        value={data[name]}
        error={errors[name]}
        onChange={this.handleChange}
      />
    )
  }
```

**here is my `antd` Select Component**

```
<Select name={name} size="medium" style={{ width: '350px' }} {...rest}>
            <Select.Option />
            {options.map((option) => (
              <Select.Option key={option._id} value={option._id}>
                {option.name || option}
              </Select.Option>
            ))}
</Select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you forget a `label` property for an `Option`?

```
              <Select.Option
                 label={option.name || option} 
                 key={option._id}
                 value={option._id}
              >
                {option.name || option}
              </Select.Option>
```

What about `handleChange`, is it take object or a string?

Comment: Select.option in antd doest support label property its only supports key , value

Comment: It does support label https://ant.design/components/select/#components-select-demo-option-label-prop

Comment: nope brother neither Select nor Select.Option has label property

Comment: What about `handleChange`, is it take object  or a string?

Comment: its takes event for the input field but select doesnt support event thats why the select value is not changing when option is selected

Answer (score 0):

you can try adding options like this

```
<Select
  defaultValue="lucy"
  style={{ width: 120 }}
  onChange={handleChange}
  options={[
    { value: 'jack', label: 'Jack' },
    { value: 'lucy', label: 'Lucy' },
    { value: 'Yiminghe', label: 'yiminghe' },
    { value: 'disabled', label: 'Disabled', disabled: true },
  ]}
/>
```

instead of using tags. Also check your options to have both `value` and `label` attributes.